# What is “the spirit of aloha”?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I’ve read this expression in a news article related to a Hawaiian politician: *“He is well-regarded in both Washington and in the islands for his gracious manner and **spirit of aloha**.”*

I understand that *aloha* is a Hawaiian greeting and, as such, I understand the expression in the quote above as “his gracious manner and openness”. I tried to look up the entire expression “spirit of aloha”, but search engines’ results are polluted by commercial uses (including a Disney show).

How would you express this sentence to exclude the Hawaiian-specific reference (if at all possible)? What are the cultural elements that I am missing (as a European who doesn't know much about Hawai, except that it's a popular holiday destination).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Aloha' is most commonly used the English language as a form of greeting, but [according to this link, it can encompass a range of thoughts / concepts related friendliness](http://www.to-hawaii.com/aloha.php). An interesting thing is mentions on that page is that 'Aloha Spirit' is a part of their state law and defined as:

> "Aloha Spirit" is the coordination of
>   mind and heart within each person. It
>   brings each person to the self. Each
>   person must think and emote good
>   feelings to others.